# Google App Engine: create deployable package of Java application

Tags: google-app-engine, java

I would like to make my App Engine application easy to install for anyone, even for non-developers. I can distribute my app with SDK included and I can wrap the install process by an easy-to-use install script or even use a GUI installer (I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/appcfgwrapper/) for example).

The problem is that JDK is required for the install process and as I have learned, it is quite complicated to properly configure the Java environment. In recent versions of App Engine SDK, there is an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8564) when JRE conflicts with JDK and the install process fails during compiling JSP files. But even without this issue, installing JDK is still an extra step that the user needs to do before deploying the app.

I've come up with to possible ways but I'm not sure whether any of them is possible:

1. "Precompile" the application and distribute it as a "ready-to-deploy" package which wouldn't require JDK to be present during the install process.
2. Somehow distribute my app together with JDK. My install package would be a closed environment with predefined paths to java and javac that would be used by included SDK. As a result, the user would just have to download one big package which would contain all required files (JDK + SDK + the app itself) and he wouldn't have download or configure anything else.

Any thoughts?